# Working with groups. Finding the inverse of some $S_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, inverse

I want to compute the inverse of:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\3&2&1&6&5&9&4&8&7 \end{pmatrix}$

Sorry about alignment(they are all one digit though)

Now it would seem that the inverse here is itself. But I feel like maybe I am just confusing myself now, and I want some confirmation. Thank you and sorry again.

Also can someone explain why my matrix above isn't formatting properly despite having two & between each element

Comment: in cycle notation, $\sigma=(13)(4697)$ which has order four (so it is not its own inverse)

Comment: @yoyo If it isn't too much effort, could you perhaps explain what that means?

Comment: It means $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 1$ and $4\mapsto 6\mapsto 9\mapsto 7\mapsto 4$. Google "cycle notation."

Comment: @Blue That explained it sufficiently, thank you(I will note, it was much more clear than Wikipedia was[although wiki had a similar setup at one point])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compute the inverse of a permutation that is written in [two-line notation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Two-line_notation_for_permutations), simply swap the two rows, then reorder the columns so that the first row goes $1,2,3\cdots,n$.

To compute the inverse of a permutation that is written in disjoint [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation), simply write each cycle backwards. In fact, even if we have a representation as a product of *non*-disjoint cycles, simply write the whole thing in reverse (so $(12)(341)(2)(3)(4)$ becomes $(4)(3)(2)(143)(21)$ for example).

Answer (score 2):

Each element in $S_9$ is a permutation (or bijection) $\{1, 2, \dots, 9\} \to \{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$. In particular, your permutation I can denote as a function $f$, where:

$$\begin{align}
f(1) &= 3\\
f(2) &= 2 \\
f(3) &= 1 \\
f(4) &= 6 \\
f(5) &= 5 \\
f(6) &= 9 \\
f(7) &= 4 \\
f(8) &= 8 \\
f(9) &= 7\text{.}
\end{align}$$ 
To compute the inverse of your permutation, notice that the inverse of $f$ exists because it is a bijection, and thus
$$\begin{align}
f^{-1}(3) &= 1\\
f^{-1}(2) &= 2 \\
f^{-1}(1) &= 3 \\
f^{-1}(6) &= 4 \\
f^{-1}(5) &= 5 \\
f^{-1}(9) &= 6 \\
f^{-1}(4) &= 7 \\
f^{-1}(8) &= 8 \\
f^{-1}(7) &= 9\text{.}
\end{align}$$ 
Hence $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\3&2&1&6&5&9&4&8&7 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5& 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 8 & 6\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$